# Using backstack in android

Tags: android, fragment-backstack

I have an issue in fragment navigation in android. I am navigating from one fragment to another and from that fragment to another. When I press the back button, I need to navigate from the third fragment to first fragment. I need to avoid the second fragment from backstack.

Here is the code I am using for adding fragment to FragmentManager

```
try {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(newFragmentType.toString(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    transaction.addToBackStack(newFragmentType.toString());
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,   newFragment,newFragmentType.toString());
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
} catch (java.lang.IllegalStateException e) {

}
```

Please help